# If $F(x) \leq cx$ for all $x >0$ then every maximal solution of $x'=F(x)$ is defined in an interval of the form $(a,+\infty)$.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Let $F: \mathbb{R} \to (0,+\infty) $ be a continuous function and $c>0$. Show that:

(1) If $F(x) \leq  cx$ for all $x >0$ then every maximal solution of $x'=F(x)$ is defined in an interval of the form $(a,+\infty)$.

(2)If $F \geq cx^2$ for all $x>0$ then no solution of $x'=F(x)$ is defined in an interval of the form $(a,+\infty)$.

can we use [Grönwall's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gr%C3%B6nwall%27s_inequality) in the first item?
the second item, I cannot develop, nor can I think about how to start the resolution.

Comment: Grönwall is the right idea for (1). For (2), you could start by solving the case $F=c x^2$.